# Spring Boot servlet context and application context problem

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlets, contextmenu, javabeans

I have a problem with contexts in Spring Boot.

I'm creating an application that has several modules, some just for backend services and others for REST services.
I'm using @Configuration to import modules into Spring Boot's main starting point.
I did the creation of servlets for the REST modules, but every time the module is started it calls the backend modules again, I'm afraid this consumes too many resources.

I need to remember that the modules are dependencies configured by maven in pom.xml.

So the auth rest module is dependent on the core module and the strategy module.

Log:

```
[main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
 o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
 o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
 o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
                            CoreModule    : ==============================================================
                            CoreModule    :            CORE MODULE INITIALIZED
                            CoreModule    : ==============================================================
                         StrategyModule   : ==============================================================
                         StrategyModule   :            STRATEGY MODULE INITIALIZED
                         StrategyModule   : ==============================================================
 br.com.llw.platform.PlatformApplication  : Started PlatformApplication in 3.816 seconds (JVM running for 4.191)
 o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'authRestDispatcherServlet'
 o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'authRestDispatcherServlet'
 d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Context refreshed
 d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Found 1 custom documentation plugin(s)
 s.d.s.w.s.ApiListingReferenceScanner     : Scanning for api listing references
 .d.s.w.r.o.CachingOperationNameGenerator : Generating unique operation named: registerUsingPOST_1
                          AuthRestConfig  : ==============================================================
                          AuthRestConfig  :            AUTH REST MODULE INITIALIZED
                          AuthRestConfig  : ==============================================================
                            CoreModule    : ==============================================================
                            CoreModule    :            CORE MODULE INITIALIZED
                            CoreModule    : ==============================================================
                         StrategyModule   : ==============================================================
                         StrategyModule   :            STRATEGY MODULE INITIALIZED
                         StrategyModule   : ==============================================================
 o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 448 ms
```

Main Class:

```
@ComponentScans(
        {
                @ComponentScan(excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(value = Controller.class, type = FilterType.ANNOTATION),}),
        }
)
@Import({
        CoreModule.class,
        StrategyModule.class,
        AuthRestAPIModuleServletConfig.class
})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class PlatformApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(new Class[]{PlatformApplication.class}, args);
    }
}
```

CoreModule.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "package")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "package")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "package")
@ImportResource({"classpath:core-spring.xml"})
public class CoreModule {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CoreModule.class);

    @EventListener
    public void handlerContextRefresh(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        LOGGER.info("==============================================================");
        LOGGER.info("\t\tCORE MODULE INITIALIZED");
        LOGGER.info("==============================================================");
    }
}
```

AuthRestConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "package")
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableWebMvc
public class AuthRestConfig {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthRestConfig.class);

    @EventListener
    public void handlerContextRefresh(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        LOGGER.info("==============================================================");
        LOGGER.info("\t\tAUTH REST MODULE INITIALIZED");
        LOGGER.info("==============================================================");
    }


    @Bean
    public Docket apiSwagger() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }

}
```

Auth Servlet Configuration

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass(AuthRestConfig.class)
public class AuthRestAPIModuleServletConfig extends AbstractApiModuleAutoConfiguration<AuthRestConfig> {

    public static final String API_MODULE_A_DISPATCHER_SERVLET_BEAN_NAME = "authRestDispatcherServlet";
    public static final String API_MODULE_A_DISPATCHER_SERVLET_REGISTRATION_BEAN_NAME = "authRestDispatcherServletRegistration";

    // @Value("${project.auth_rest.path}")
    private static final String apiModulePath = "/auth";

    @Bean(name = API_MODULE_A_DISPATCHER_SERVLET_BEAN_NAME)
    public DispatcherServlet apiModuleDispatcherServlet() {
        return createApiModuleDispatcherServlet();
    }

    @Bean(name = API_MODULE_A_DISPATCHER_SERVLET_REGISTRATION_BEAN_NAME)
    public ServletRegistrationBean moduleDispatcherServletRegistration() {
        return createApiModuleDispatcherServletRegistration(apiModuleDispatcherServlet());
    }

    @Override
    protected String getApiModuleDispatcherServletBeanName() {
        return API_MODULE_A_DISPATCHER_SERVLET_BEAN_NAME;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getApiModulePath() {
        return apiModulePath;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<AuthRestConfig> getApiModuleConfigurationClass() {
        return AuthRestConfig.class;
    }
}
```

Abstract Servlet Configuration Class

```
public abstract class AbstractApiModuleAutoConfiguration<T> {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AbstractApiModuleAutoConfiguration.class);

    @Autowired
    protected ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    protected ServerProperties server;

    @Autowired(required = false)
    protected MultipartConfigElement multipartConfig;

    @Value("${project.rest.base-api-path}")
    protected String baseApiPath;

    protected DispatcherServlet createApiModuleDispatcherServlet() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        webContext.setParent(applicationContext);
        webContext.register(getApiModuleConfigurationClass());
        return new DispatcherServlet(webContext);
    }

    protected ServletRegistrationBean createApiModuleDispatcherServletRegistration(DispatcherServlet apiModuleDispatcherServlet) {
        String path = baseApiPath + getApiModulePath() + "/*";
        LOGGER.info("REGISTER SERVLET: " + path);
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(apiModuleDispatcherServlet, path);


        registration.setName(getApiModuleDispatcherServletBeanName());
        if (this.multipartConfig != null) {
            registration.setMultipartConfig(this.multipartConfig);
        }
        return registration;
    }

    protected abstract String getApiModuleDispatcherServletBeanName();

    protected abstract String getApiModulePath();

    protected abstract Class<T> getApiModuleConfigurationClass();
}
```

How to avoid these duplicate calls?

Comment: please post the code directly instead of using picture.thanks

Comment: Adjusted. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand why you are doing this in Spring if you are scanning the root package. Once your app starts everything is in the memory and there's no separation of concerns. Why is it that separate pom modules is not enough?

Comment: I would like to isolate the modules, so that I can work with specific configurations in each one.
Do you think it's a bad idea what I'm doing?

I thought about starting like this because when the project is too big, it might be necessary to split it.

Comment: A Eduardo, já que é brasileiro fica mais fácil explicar em português kk. 

A idéia é que o projeto creça muito, então tenho medo de que ter apenas um contexto possa me trazer problemas quando precisar isolar as configurações. Você acha uma má idéia? Também quero ver se consigo isolar o suficiente para caso no futuro eu necessite separar o projeto as coisas estejam encaminhadas. 

O meu problema é, toda vez que eu inicio a aplicação, ele chama os módulso Core e Strategy. Quando eu faço uma request para o Servlet, ele chama novamente esses módulos, acredito que para inciializa-los.

Comment: Qual os problemas que eu já encontrei. 
Definir um path inicial para o servlet no spring. Quando a configuração é unificada, ele vai ser o mesmo para todos os endpoints. Declarando o servlet consigo fazer isso de forma isolada. Também tem as configurations que consigo isolar melhor dessa forma.

Comment: Não sei até onde o projeto pode crescer sendo apenas o "Spring boot" padrão.